How to get some metadata from client in @ConnectMapping for RSocket Java Spring
I now receive an rsocket connection in my spring project, and then I want to read some metadata from the client which initiated the connection, how should I pass/retrieve it?
@ConnectMapping
public void connectMapping(RSocketRequester requester, String somePayload) {
    // Use the somePayload
}

